# How to connect to Kafka in Kubernetes from outside?

Tags: amazon-web-services, kubernetes, apache-kafka, confluent-platform

The challenge is to create a Kafka producer that connects to a Kafka cluster that lives within a Kubernetes cluster from outside that cluster. We have several RDBMS databases that sit on premise and we want to stream data directly to Kafka that lives in Kubernetes on AWS. We have tried a few things and deployed the Confluent Open Source Platform but nothing worked so far. Does anyone have a clear answer to this problem?

Comment: What exactly did you try? Have you checked Kafka Connect?

Comment: Yes I looked at Kafka Connect but would rather create producers that connect directly to the cluster

Comment: In general, you need an Ingress Load Balancer/Proxy Controller for any client to connect from the outside.

Comment: Kafka Connect **is** a producer

Comment: Kafka cluster say has 3 brokers. We created 3 LBs on AWS for each one of those brokers. Unfortunately this does not seem to work at all.

Comment: Kafka Connect has specific available connectors and doesn't support everything we need. On top of that we want to have fine grained control of each producer and add plenty of monitoring, logging and recovery functionality in there

Comment: @Dimitris Kafka Connect produces its own task-specific logs which are quite verbose. Monitoring can also be achieved through Kafka Connect REST Interface (https://docs.confluent.io/current/connect/references/restapi.html). KC also provides scalability and parallelism (see connector's tasks). IMO, if you want to create your own producers you are going to spend a lot of time in order to re-invent the wheel. What source databases do you have?

Comment: Oracle, MySQL, PostgreSQL and MongoDB source and sink. Does Kafka Connect use REST to push the data?

Comment: This article should give a clear explanation of how KC works: https://www.linkedin.com/pulse/kafka-connect-why-exists-how-works-chandan-prakash. Do you also need to capture the changes in the source databases?  If so, you might need a third-party CDC tool (e.g. for Oracle, you'd need Oracle GoldenGate or Attunity Replicate).

Comment: Unfortunately most of our data sits in Oracle databases which is why we were looking for something more basic compared to Connect. We've looked into GoldenGate but that seems to be overly complicated to set up

Comment: As far as licensing is not a problem you can go for Attunity Replicate. The configuration is not that hard, and the User Interface is quite friendly.

Answer (score 0):

You might have a look at deploying [Kafka Connect](https://docs.confluent.io/current/connect/index.html) inside of Kubernetes. Since you want to replicate data from various RDMBS databases, you need to setup *source connectors*,

> A source connector ingests entire databases and streams table updates
>   to Kafka topics. It can also collect metrics from all of your
>   application servers into Kafka topics, making the data available for
>   stream processing with low latency.

Depending on your source databases, you'd have to configure the corresponding [connectors](https://docs.confluent.io/current/connect/managing/connectors.html).

If you are not familiar with Kafka Connect, [this article](https://docs.confluent.io/current/connect/concepts.html#kconnect-long-concepts) might be quite helpful as it explains the key concepts.

Comment: As my above answer we have very specific workloads and need to connect directly to the cluster. We don't want to use REST Proxy or anything like that, just produce data directly to Kafka topics.

Answer (score 0):

Kafka clients need to connect to specific node to produce or consume messages.

The kafka protocol can connect to any node to get metadata. Then the client connects to  a specific node which has been elected as leader of the partition which the client wants to produce/consume.

Each kafka pod has to be individually accessible, so you need a L4 load balancer per pod. The advertised listener config can be set in the kafka config to advertise different IP/hostname for internal and external clients. Configure the ADVERTISED_LISTENERS EXTERNAL to use the load balancer, and the INTERNAL to use pod IP. The ports has to be different for internal and external.

Checkout https://strimzi.io/, https://bitnami.com/stack/kafka, https://github.com/confluentinc/cp-helm-charts

> Update:
>
> Was trying out installing kafka in k8s running in AWS EC2. Between
> confluent-operator, bitnami-kafka and strimzi, only strimzi configured
> EXTERNAL in the kafka settings to the load balancer.
>
> bitnami-kafka used
> headless service, which is not useful outside the k8s network.
> Confluent-operator configures to node's IP which makes it accessible
> outside k8s, but to those who can reach the EC2 instance via private
> IP.